# Change content based on referrer

Tags: java, html

I would like to change an outgoing link based on the referrer.

So, if a visitor comes from facebook, I would like to display a different outgoing link. What I tried so far and that works, is simply to use the referrer to redirect users coming from facebook to a different index file, where I changed the outgoing link. But I think this is overkill and might have negative effects on the SEO of the site so I would like something simpler.

Ideally I would like something that names a variable based on the outcome of the if statement. So (my html knowledge is extremely limited, so the nomenclature and syntax may be a bit off here):

```
    if(visitor comes from facebook) {
     link = "https://link1.com"
    } else {
     link = "https://link2.com"
    }

    <a href=link>outgoing link</a>
```

I know this might not be possible with html, but I think the aim is clear.
The code below is what I use now and it works, but I would like something that doesn't require a redirect of the visitor. I also don't want to use php.

```
    <script>
       var referrer =  document.referrer;
       if(referrer.indexOf("facebook") > -1) {          
        document.location = "index1.html";    
       }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(visitor comes from facebook) {
     document.getElementById("myLink").href = "https://link1.com"
} else {
     document.getElementById("myLink").href = "https://link2.com"
}
</script>


<a href="#" id="myLink">outgoing link</a>
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm using it wrong, but this link just goes to "mysite.com/#", it just ads the hashtag at the end of the URL, this is exactly how the script looks like now: 
`<script type="text/javascript">
     var referrer =  document.referrer;
   if(referrer.indexOf("facebook") > -1) {
     document.getElementById("myLink").href = "https://link1.com"
} else {
     document.getElementById("myLink").href = "https://link2.com"
}
</script>`
And link:
`<a href="#" id="myLink">outgoing link</a>`

Comment: Add it into function and call it

<script type="text/javascript">
  
  function checkVisitedLink(){
    var referrer = document.referrer;
     if(referrer.indexOf("facebook") > -1) {
        document.getElementById("myLink").href = "https://link1.com"
     }else {
      document.getElementById("myLink").href = "https://link2.com"
     }
  }
  checkVisitedLink();
</script>

Comment: I'm sorry, my html knowledge is very limited, I can't get it to work. I added this to the head of the file and then the link, as you wrote it in the first comment, in the body of the file, that should be it?

Comment: No :-( This is exactly what's in the header:
`<script type="text/javascript"> function checkVisitedLink(){ var referrer = document.referrer; 
 if(referrer.indexOf("facebook") > -1) { document.getElementById("myLink").href = "link1.com" 
 }
 else { document.getElementById("myLink").href = "link2.com" } 
 } checkVisitedLink(); 
</script>`

And this is the link in the body:

`<a href="#" id="myLink">outgoing link</a>`

The link just redirects me to "mysite.com/#", do I need to adjust the code somehow?

Comment: Try this
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="myLink">outgoing link</a>
     <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function checkVisitedLink(){ 
        var referrer = document.referrer; 
        if(true) { 
            console.log(document.getElementById("myLink"));
            document.getElementById("myLink").href = "link1.com";
        } else { 
            document.getElementById("myLink").href = "link2.com";
        }
    } 
    checkVisitedLink(); 
</script>
</body>
</html>